# Within section numbering of figures: missing period

Tags: floats, chngcntr

For a while, I have been using within section numbering of figures.  This used to be done by adding the `chngcntr` package (which is no longer needed) and `\counterwithin`.

However, now instead of the Figure appearing as Figure 1.1 it appears as Figure 11 --- below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{article}
\counterwithin{figure}{section} 
\begin{document}

\section{fake section}

\begin{figure}[h]
xyz 
\caption{TBA}
\label{fig:tba}     
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here it appears as `Figure 1.1: TBA`.

Comment: Sorry, I must be dense.  Where do you see it as appearing as Figure 1.1?  When I compile it (I'm using textmate and pdflatex) i get Figure 11.

Comment: I compiled your code now with `pdflatex` from TeXlive 2018.

Comment: Hmm. Based on your comment, I reinstalled MacTex to see if it was something wrong with my version.  It still compiles as Figure 11. Does anyone have a clue on why this can happen?

Comment: Try to compile directly from terminal, without editor, to make sure which version you are using.

Comment: I just tried compiling from terminal without the editor and had the same issue. in case this helps, potentially relevant info: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2